# Solution of a set of coupled first oder partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We are given that $\hat{A}$ is a matrix

$$
\hat A =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} & a_{03} \\
a_{10} & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{20} & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{30} & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\pmb{a}_{0} & \pmb{a}_{1} & \pmb{a}_{2} & \pmb{a}_{3} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $a_{ij} = a_{ij}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and a matrix $\hat M = \text{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$ such that

$$
{\hat A}^T \cdot \hat M \cdot \hat A = \text{diag} \left(1,\frac{1}{g_{11}},\frac{1}{g_{22}},\frac{1}{g_{33}} \right)
$$

with $g_{11} = g_{11}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $g_{22} = g_{22}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $g_{33} = -\frac{1}{g_{11} g_{22}}$. Based on these definitions, the following system of 24 differential equations has to be solved

$$
( \text{grad} \ln \sqrt{g_{kk}} )^T \cdot 
\left( 
a_{i0}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{j1} \\
a_{j2} \\
a_{j3}  
\end{pmatrix}
-
a_{j0}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{i1} \\
a_{i2} \\
a_{i3}  
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
+ \partial_k (a_{i0} a_{jk} - a_{ik} a_{j0}) = \pmb{0}$$

for $k=1,2,3$ and $(i,j)=(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)$ and

$$
\text{div} 
\left( 
a_{i0}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{j1} \\
a_{j2} \\
a_{j3}  
\end{pmatrix}
-
a_{j0}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{i1} \\
a_{i2} \\
a_{i3}  
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
= 0 \tag 2$$

for $(i,j)=(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)$, where $\text{grad}$ and $\text{div}$ are in 3-dimensional Cartesian coordinates.

The question is: **What is the solution of the set of differential equations defined in $(1)$ and $(2)$ under given restrictions?**

It is possible to rewrite these differential equation in a matrix form. With definition ${\hat T}_i = \pmb{a}_0 \cdot \pmb{a}_i^T - \pmb{a}_i \cdot \pmb{a}_0^T $, which is a dyadic product substracted by its transposed, we can rewrite $(1)$ with

$$
{\hat \rho}_k =
\partial_1 \ln \sqrt{g_{kk}} \  {\hat T}_1 +
\partial_2 \ln \sqrt{g_{kk}} \  {\hat T}_2 +
\partial_3 \ln \sqrt{g_{kk}} \  {\hat T}_3 +
\partial_k {\hat T}_k = \hat 0 \tag 3$$

for $k=1,2,3$ and

$$
\partial_1 {\hat T}_1 +
\partial_2 {\hat T}_2 +
\partial_3 {\hat T}_3 = \hat 0 \tag 4
$$

With $(4)$ and $g_{33} = -\frac{1}{g_{11} g_{22}}$ we can see, that ${\hat \rho}_1 + {\hat \rho}_2 + {\hat \rho}_3 = \hat 0$.

Comment: Dear Matthew Cassell, please be so kind to correct your editis. Equation (1) is not numbered. I would appreciate if you would also provide constructive input into the solution rather than just making beautifications.